# ListView.SelectedItem does not change when the property of the bound ConfigurationElement has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, configurationelement

I have a class derived from `ConfigurationElement` as follows:

```
public class Item : ConfigurationElement, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Binding Properties.
    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", DefaultValue = null, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this["Name"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            this["Name"] = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Methods.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    // ctor.
    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged members.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I have a View which contains a `ListView`, as follow:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Modify" Command="{Binding ModifyCommand}"/>
    <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">            
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

The ViewModel for the View is as follow:

```
public class MainViewModel : Observant
{
    // Fields.
    public Item m_SelectedItem;

    // Binding Properties.
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_SelectedItem != value)
            {
                m_SelectedItem = value;
                // Updated.
                NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            }
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand ModifyCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // ctor.
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ModifyCommand = new RelayCommand(Modify_Execute);
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item("Bird"));
        Items.Add(new Item("Bug"));
        Items.Add(new Item("Cat"));
        Items.Add(new Item("Dog"));
        Items.Add(new Item("Fish"));
        Items.Add(new Item("Sheep"));
        Items.Add(new Item("Shrimp"));
    }

    private void Modify_Execute(object parameter)
    {
        m_SelectedItem.Name = string.Format("{0}-{1}", m_SelectedItem.Name, DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    }
}
```

where `Observant` is a base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

After selecting an item in the `ListView`, I've update the item in the ViewModel thru `SelectedItem` property (by clicking on the Modify button) and it went well. However, when I attempt to select another item after modifying current item, current item does not get deselected, as follow:

[image]

I'm aware that `Item` has different implementation of property getter and setter when compared to implementation that uses field. It is implemented as such because the `Item` is part of the configuration which is loaded from / persisted to a configuration file.

My question is: Is it possible correct this without using the getter/setter that uses field?

Comment: `ListView.MultiSelect = false`?

Comment: I use `SelectionMode=Single` instead. It works for removing the highlight from the current item to the new clicked item, but ListView.SelectedItem is not updated as further clicking on the Modify button updates the previous item instead of the new item.